# How can I force save in GTA Online without leaving?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I know when you leave GTA Online it's *supposed* to save, however I think the loss of money/properties/levels is caused by it *saving* when the cloud servers are offline.

So my question is, is there anything I can do in a session to force it to save automatically, so if I save it 10 times within half an hour, hopefully at least one of those times the cloud servers are online and it will save.

I'm asking because I lost 5 levels and 200k yesterday, and I've made a lot of money today.

Also, this may not be the cause of why data is being lost, but I'd like to at least give myself as good a chance as possible of saving it.

Comment: As far as I know after you do a successful mission given to you via text the social club saving/loading icon appears. I don't know if it saves your character or if it just updates highscores, but thats all I can tell you.

Comment: well, I've done missions, bought cars, sold cars, done everything. still lost my level 30 character with $1m. don't think it helps anyway

Comment: I haven't tried online yet, but in single you bring up your phone and there's a cloud icon that allows you to quick save. Does Online not have that option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you save on GTA Online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262866/how-can-you-save-on-gta-online) Voting to close as a dupe of a newer question because the newer question has more views (112k over 59k), and more importantly, has more answers with multiple correct solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I lost a bunch of money and XP, too. Really annoying.

If you're in a solo session, you can usually do missions and your progress seems to be saved after every successfully completed mission, but you can't be sure if the servers are really up and did save your progress.

Link your account to the [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/), if you haven't already. Now open the [online progression tracker](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/career/overview/gtaonline) (requires login) when you start the game and refresh it when you'd like to stop playing. Compare the XP/money earned with your actual progress. If your character is further than this page acutally shows, there is no other way than forcing a save by completing missions until your progress is saved and shows correctly on the Rockstar Social Club page. I just checked, presuming the servers are available, this site updates within a few minutes.

That's not a real solution - and if you're unlucky, you might be stuck in this progress for hours (in my experience usually around 17-23 o'clock GMT). But currently, that's just the way it is, until Rockstar gets their servers under control.

But at least, this way you can actually check your saved progress without leaving and possible losing money or XP.

Answer (score -2):

just buy bicycle and it will save your progress