# How can you save on GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I can't seem to be able to save on Grand Theft Auto Online on my Xbox 360. I've tried using the phone but I can't see a save icon. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

It saves automatically after certain important events. If you want to be sure that it saves when you stop playing you can leave the GTA online session by either of these methods:

- Press start and quit.
- Hold down on the d-pad and select one of the 3 campaign characters.

Then it will auto save.

Personally I use the d-pad down and select a campaign character.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can try:

- Change your style
- Change your appearance
- Do a quick and easy mission (such as Special Cargo)

These should force the game to save

Comment: It seems that changing your style or appearance is the easiest way to save out of all the other methods mentioned so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you can do to force GTA Online to save your progress:

- Change from GTA Online to GTA V from the Character Wheel or Pause Menu
- Do a monetary transaction like purchasing snacks or selling vehicles (since 1.05)
- Change the session from the pause menu

The easiest way to know if the game is being saved is to see if the yellow spinning circle is present at the bottom right of the screen.

Answer (score -3):

If you register as a CEO or motorcycle club it saves your game.

Comment: This doesn't seem detailed. Can you elaborate?